# How can I multiply two number using bitwise, if one is a decimal?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Since bitwise operators work only for int, how do I go about multiplying 4 and 8.25. I came across this as a practice problem.
I can represent 4 as binary digit `0b100` and that's just about all I understand. Even the algorithms on YouTube just go about bitwise division. If anyone can give a hint on this or guide me to some good resources on this, it would be appreciated. How can 8.25 be presented as a binary?

Comment: floating point numbers are stored in a format with mantissa and exponent. You can do bitwise operations on floats by converting the number from float to int by by multiplying 10**power and dividing by the same to get the float back.

Comment: Have you read the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) article on floating-point arithmetic? It describes both have they are represented in binary and how arithmetic operations are done.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do the math. One, if you have 2 decimal places is to multiply everything by 100 first. Python just uses the processor's math rules for floats in doubles. Likely its [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). The `decimal` module does [Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html).

Comment: Check this article   https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#floating-point-numbers